# Изображение привязать к фигуре и поворачивать ее в Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно сделать компас, часть которой должна быть невидимой. Для этого картинку  шкалы привязать к эллипсу так, чтобы при изменении значения компаса смещался центр и был виден только часть картинки. Допустим, если компас показывает 0 он на нуле, если 5, то центр смещается на пять. То что внутри  прямоугольника это часть, которая должна быть видимой. Каким образом можно привязать картину к фигуре?